# 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' giving error message

Tags: dpkg

```
dpkg: error processing package linux-signed-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic
 linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
 linux-generic-lts-utopic
 linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic
 linux-image-3.16.0-031600-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic
 linux-signed-image-3.13.0-66-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-signed-image-generic
 linux-signed-generic
```

Comment: Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Raphael Ubuntu version is 14.04 LTS

Comment: Can you please type the exact command you typed before you got the error?

Comment: {sudo dpkg --configure -a}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need remove all the unconfigured packages using the following commands, but be careful not to remove the current kernel version you are using. You can find that out with the uname -r command.

```
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.16.0-52-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-generic-lts-utopic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-generic-lts-utopic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.13.0-66-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-3.16.0-031600-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-extra-3.16.0-52-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-signed-image-3.13.0-66-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-extra-3.13.0-66-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-signed-image-generic
 sudo dpkg --purge linux-signed-generic
```

and then to fix package dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

After it you can get back to what you were doing, and the `sudo dpkg --configure -a` command should not give you any errors.